# windows efi and system reserved partition mistakenly deleted

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, uefi

while installing ubuntu mistakenly deleted windows efi partition, and other system reserved drive.

Currently i am with ubuntu n how many times i try to install dual boot with windows it was not working. it was not loading windows 10 it was completly blank and boot to ubuntu.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your response.
after two days googling finally found a solution.

I have downloadded **Hiren's BootCD**, Bootable into Pendrive,
it will load the UI, after that i have downloaded and windows 10 iso from microsoft and i have installed it by choosing desired drive, which i have allocated for windows 10.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8.1, 10, and 11 can live without the recovery partition but not the UEFI partition (which part of the startup sequence) which is needed for Windows to function.  I am pretty sure you will have to start again with Windows (I do not know of any way to backfill the UEFI partition to make Windows start).

So you need to reinstall Windows and then see about adding Ubuntu afterwards. I use a Virtual Machine for Ubuntu.

Comment: while installing Ubuntu i was deleted all my drives make it clean without any leftover, i tried 20 times with Another Laptop used rufus and windows 10 21h1, while selecting in bootmenu for usb drive and then it was blank and it was booting to ubuntu.

Comment: @DevG - Your question makes no mention of you deleting all your partitions on the drive.  You only mentioned you deleted a single partition, one that is required to exist, in order to boot into Windows

Comment: If you cannot install Windows from ISO, you may learn to like Ubuntu.